# GPO for PS1 logon script does not work without local admin rights for user

Tags: powershell, group-policy, login-script

I have a PowerShell .PS1 script that I am trying to get to apply via a logon script with Group Policy. Here is the .PS1 script (very simple, just adds the user to RD Users group):

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" /add
```

According to `RSoP.msc` and `GPresult`, the GPO is getting applied without issue. I can run the PS1 manually and it works (albeit as Admin and with `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`). However, the script is not working, because the user logging in never gets added to the "Remote Desktop Users" group.

In `RSoP.msc` under "last executed" time it is blank for the script. I'd like to look in Event Viewer to get a better idea of why the script isn't working, but am not sure what to look for exactly.

**EDIT:** Apparently the logon script *must* run as the logged on user, so it inherits whatever permissions said user has (or rather, does not have). I am going to try and run the script computer-side to see if it will work without the end-user having local admin rights since it will be using a system account.

Comment: What's the script execution policy?

Comment: It's not specified, at least not in the script or the GPO. Should it be?

Comment: ...perhaps a .BAT file would be better? All I need to do is add %username% to the RD Users group, should be easy.

Comment: The batch file is working.

Comment: ...not reliably though.

Comment: Run Get-ExecutionPolicy to see the current policy. By default, it's Restricted.

Comment: Thanks, @Davidw. I don't think that's the issue though. Per an article by PS guru Jeffery Hicks "Group Policy scripts will always run, regardless of your local script execution policy. Even if your execution policy is restricted Group Policy scripts will still run using a Bypass policy." via: https://4sysops.com/archives/configuring-logon-powershell-scripts-with-group-policy/

Comment: Worth noting that the batch file script is not working either. What I really need to know is where to look in the Event Log, and for what exactly.

Comment: Try using &"net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" /add" in the script. That will invoke it as cmd.exe, rather than Powershell.

Comment: What about using %LogonUser% in a GPP, could that work?

Comment: I can get the command to run from the command line, and from the script, but it won't run from Group Policy.

Comment: @Davidw, Local Admin rights are required get the GPO to work. They *shouldn't* be, but from my tests, they are.

Comment: Perhaps elevation within the script?

Comment: Looks like the only way to get it to run as local admin is third party tools.

Comment: What 3rd party tools?

Comment: make it a start up script won't work either unless you know which user to add (i.e. hardcoding user name).

Comment: What about this GPO? Computer Config > Policies > Admin Templates > System > Logon: Run these programs at user logon (the PS1 script)

Comment: I'm trying a slightly different tack, running it from a scheduled task using group policy.

Comment: It appears that it's not working as a scheduled task either. Computer Config > Policies > Admin Templates > System > Logon: Run these programs at user logon (the PS1 script) is for setting which script runs first.

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve?  I only ask because adding domain users to local groups is not best practice.  (Users go in  Global Groups, Global Groups go in Local Groups + give permissions to local groups, UGLP).  Maintaining your solution will be greatly simplified if you can make a solution that uses this framework.  Having a global remote users group in the local remote users group would allow you to add users to the global group easily.  Also, if you need to restrict it, another option might be to use GP managed groups.  Not sure it can be used for local groups.

Comment: @Xalorous, I am simply trying to add $user to his/her the local RD User Group (the PS1 script does this). The 'local' part is non-negiotable and unless I'm missing something, what you wrote about best-practice is just not applicable to my situation. The user *must* have membership in the ***local* Remote Desktop Users Group in order to RDP into the machine**. 1 single user, 1 single machine. There is no other way to simplify the solution anymore than this.

Comment: @KidACrimson Are they logging in locally, AND they need to be able to remote in?  I'm still trying to understand the requirements.

Comment: Correct, they come into the office to work, but also work from home occasionally. Each person just uses his/her own computer either locally or remotely via VPN, hence the need for said person's membership in RD Users Group.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run it as a scheduled task deployed via Group Policy, using System as the account to run the scheduled task.

Create a new scheduled task under `Computer Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Scheduled Tasks`, choosing the `Scheduled Task (Windows Vista and Later)` task type:

[image: Task type]

[image: Task location]

Set the account to `NT AUTHORITY/System`, and set to `run with highest privileges`:
[image: Task privilage]

Set it to trigger `at log on` of `any user`:
[image: ![Task trigger]

Select `Start a program` under `action`, set `Powershell.exe` as the program/script, and the path to the script as the argument:
[image: Task action]

Leave all other tabs unchanged.

When the user logs in, they should see a powershell window show up, and by checking lusrmgr.msc, you should see the user in the specified group:
[image: User added to the group]

Comment: Excellent info, David! I will try this out ASAP...

Comment: I tried, but could not get this to work. Thank you anyhow though.

Comment: same here , No luck :(